# How to find the Qtreewidgetitem on button click of a QPushbutton which is added on that Qtreewidgetitem?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have the following UI. the buttons and the QlineEdit (test, test2) are added on QtreeWidgetItems. I want to edit the text of QlineEdit on click of QPushButton.

How can i get the QtreeWidgetItem of the QPushButton on its click?

Once I get the QtreeWidgetItem, i can traverse to its QlineEdit and change the text.

[image]

Comment: Could not find any solution yet, tried for the similar solution in C++, but no success yet. I need it in Python.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. M pretty new to writing queries on Stackoverflow.